# how show the date/time of last page refresh on top of google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm new here and have built a simple google map page based on the Hello, World sample here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

I've added a meta statement to refresh the page every 5 minutes.  Is there a way i can display the date/time of the last refresh on top of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an element to the dom somewhere:

```
<div id = "time" > - </div>
```

Then whenever you update the page, do this:

```
document.getElementById("time").textContent = "" + new Date();
```